# python: read dna sequence text file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dna-sequence

I'm trying to convert a text file containing DNA sequences to a dictionary in python. The file is setup in columns.

```
TTT F
TCT S
TAT Y
TGT C
TTC F


import os.path

if os.path.isfile("GeneticCode_2.txt"):
    f = open('GeneticCode_2.txt', 'r')
    my_dict = eval(f.read())
```

Trying to get it to:

```
my_dict = {TTT: F, TCT: S, TAT: Y}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dict` constructor using an iterable of pairs (2-tuples) and pass it the split lines of your file:

```
with open('GeneticCode_2.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_dict = dict(line.split() for line in f)  
    # works only if file only contains lines that split into exactly 2 tokens
```

Comment: When I try this this following error occurs: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #64 has length 0; 2 is required

Comment: There is probably an empty line in your file. You can check for such lines.

Comment: Solved, there few a few extra spaces at the bottom of the text file, working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
with open("GeneticCode_2.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        k,v = line.strip().split()
        d[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most compact way of doing it, but it is very readable.

```
my_dict = dict()

for line in f.readlines():
    parts = line.strip().split()
    if not len(parts) < 2:
        my_dict[parts[0]] = parts[1]
```